# Finding differential from 3 sampled points

Tags: differential-geometry

I have 3 equidistant sampled points with values (-1,ym1), (0,y0), (1,y1). I would like to find an exact differential at point (0,y0). Is this doable at all, or should I evaluate the whole sampled data (which is around 1000 points long) somehow?

Comment: Are you points with errors or not ?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unacurate ,I am thinking about acoording to the tyler series  $$\ (I) f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+O(h^3) $$

$$ (II) f(x-h) = f(x) - hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+O(h^3) 
 \ O(h^3) $$

now $(I)-(II) \to\ f(x+h) - f(x-h) = 2hf'(x)+O(h^3)  $ s:

$$f'(x)= \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}$$

You can take h to be 1 ,but its kind of a bad way to do this.(by the way i have learned that  this numeric method  called "central derivative" i couldent find it in wiki so i am not sure about the name).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference